# Fujitsu Lifebook A531

Tags: laptop, charger

I bought my Fujitsu laptop in Sweden can I use the charger it came with with an adaptor in USA. It seems like my battery is not staying charged as long after using in in USA for about 1 month. Wondering if I am frying my battery..

Comment: Does the AC adapter indicate it supports 110/120V?

Answer (score 1):

Most any laptop from recent years comes with an AC adapter that accepts "universal" voltage. You can confirm by checking your adapter and verifying that it says "100-240V" or similar.

If your battery doesn't seem to last as long as it used to, maybe you use it a lot, or you're doing different things, or you're draining it down all the way before recharging, or your battery is defective, or any number of possibilities, really.